# Disable prevent default in child element

Tags: javascript

I have navigation list where I have to add a e.preventDefault() method to stop creating a hash in the url. I have a child element which is a popup/dropdown menu and it also a list of links. The e.preventDefault from the parent navigation list affecting the childElement. Tried adding e.stopPropagation() but it did not work. How can I disable that?

**Parent navigation list:**

```
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="navigation__list">
    <li>
      <a href="#about" class="navigation__link">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#projects" class="navigation__link">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact" class="navigation__link">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="navigation__inline navigation__connect">Connect</span>
      <div class="popup">
        <ul class="popup__list">
          <li class="popup__item">
            <a href="#" class="popup__link" target="_blank">
              <span class="popup__title">Gmail</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="popup__item">
            <a href="#" class="popup__link" target="_blank">
              <span class="popup__title">Instagram</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="popup__item">
            <a href="#" class="popup__link" target="_blank">
              <span class="popup__title">LinkedIn</span>
            </a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
class MenuView {
  _navigationList = document.querySelector('.navigation__list');

  constructor() {
    this._addHandlerScrollIntoView();
  }

  scrollIntoSection(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const link = e.target.classList.contains('navigation__link');

    if(link) {
      const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
      document.querySelector(id).scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    }
  }

  _addHandlerScrollIntoView() {
    this._navigationList.addEventListener('click', this.scrollIntoSection.bind(this))
  }
}
```

**Popup List**

```
class PopupView {
  _btnPopup = document.querySelector('.navigation__connect');

  constructor() {
    this._addShowHidePopup();
  }

  _togglePopup() {
    this._parentElement.classList.toggle('active');
  }

  _addShowHidePopup() {
    this._btnPopup.addEventListener('click', this._togglePopup.bind(this));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use e.stopImmediatePropagation()

Comment: Where I can put that?

Comment: when you write a function like btn.addEventListener('click',e=> {
e.stopImmediatePropagation();

// your code
});

Comment: It doesn't work.